# Create a Flutter project with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, android-studio, flutter

Flutter allows to support of `Swift` programming language.

[image: "Include Swift support for iOS code" in "Create New Flutter Project"]

How can I integrate my `Swift` code file with Flutter project in Android Studio.

[image]

There is no option to add/create a Swift file (in `New` menu) in Android Studio.

Comment: did you try to just create an empty file and explicitly set its extension to `.swift`? that would be the first thing I would try :)

Comment: Isn't Flutter compile its source to Swift?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flutter uses Dart language.

Android - Java/Kotlin , iOS - Objc/Swift could be used to write plugins and platform dependent code. More details https://flutter.io/developing-packages/

When Flutter creates new project, it generates 2 native projects (iOS and Android), that would be able to run compiled Flutter project. Languages are selected via menu you posted. Check `ios` and `android` folders in created project.

Answer (score 23):

I think a better way is to create Flutter project by command line:

**// Update 2021**

In the terminal in a desired directory run command

```
flutter create --org com.yourdomain your_app_name
```

Swift, Kotlin, and Androidx dependencies are the default options

After you can develop it in IDE that suits for you

Full command for production can look like

```
flutter create --org com.yourcompany --description 'Your App Description' your_app_name
```

Params

```
--org com.yourcompany
```

will form applicationId for Android:

```
com.yourcompany.yourappname
```

and iOS PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER:

```
com.yourcompany.yourAppName
```

parameter

```
--description 'Your App Description'
```

sets package description in our pubspec.yaml

Comment: The OP want to add new swift file from android studio( Which is not possible ) on a already created flutter project. Your answer seems wrong ;)

Comment: this does not answer the original question about adding a `.swift` file to the project.

Answer (score 9):

Creating project in:

**iOS: Swift, Android: Kotlin**

```
flutter create -i swift -a kotlin package_name
```

---

**iOS: Swift, Android: Java**

```
flutter create -i swift -a java package_name
```

---

**iOS: Objective-C, Android: Kotlin**

```
flutter create -i objc -a kotlin package_name
```

---

**iOS: Objective-C, Android: Java**

```
flutter create -i objc -a java package_name
```

---

#### Note:

Using above commands, you'll see the company name created is `example`, so to add your company name, simply add `--org com.company` right after `flutter create` like:

```
flutter create --org com.company -i swift -a kotlin package_name
```

Comment: **Example:** `flutter create -i swift -a java --org com.company app_name` Package name will be: com.company.app_name

Answer (score 1):

the best option will be to open your ios folder in xcode and add and edit your code there

Comment: I read this question as how to add/create swift files with flutter. Though the OP does say Android Studio by name, this seems the better answer. Using Android Studio to edit swift would be like using a screwdriver to pound in a nail, IMO.